# Why in gwt a 120px wide listbox is shorter than a 120px wide textbox?

Tags: css, gwt, widget

I'm working on a simple GWT app.

I have a `FlexTable`, inside of it there are labels and input widgets (e.g. listbox, textbox, date picker...), with this pattern:
LABEL INPUT LABEL INPUT
LABEL INPUT LABEL INPUT
and so on, so I have two columns of input fields with their descriptions.
I forced a `setwidth("120px")` on each one of these input widget, so I would expect them to be lined up (vertically). but they are not! a listbox element is shorter than the textbox, with no apparent reason.
Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 1):

There are **should be** apparent reasons, I've also tried your case but I haven't faced such issue, it should be from your side try using firebug you can find something from there. Here is what I got with the code that you described, I didn't add any css style except `setWidth("120px")`:
[image]

Comment: i followed your suggestion and inspected the generated html code with firebux, here is is: <select class="gwt-ListBox" style="width: 120px;"> and <input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox" style="width: 120px;">... and yet the listbox is smaller...

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with this link should give you a better understanding. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/z5UnT/)

A 120px wide textbox will be 120 wide, then the border is added (1px either side) , and the padding (1px either side) is added too, making 124px wide text box.
In a list box however the total width including the border and padding will be 120.
The key here is if you want a textbox with a width of 120px, and you have a border of 1px each side and padding 1px each side then you need to set your width to 116px. Keep the select as 120px though.

Comment: there is something here i'm not understanding... u are suggesting that a textbox has padding and border and the listbox does not? i saw that in fiddle your explanation works, but still if i change the width for listbox to 125px (even one pixel more than what u are suggesting), the listbox is shorter than the textbox... and adapt the measures this way is really a crappy way to do this stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrestling with 2 different box models. If you set both to `box-sizing:border-box` (may need vendor prefixes) then you will see consistent rendering.

See here: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/